# Can't view the attachments

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, fauxton

I have installed CouchDB 2.1.1 downloaded from `http://couchdb.apache.org/` in Red Hat enterprise Linux 7.4. As usual I am using the "Fauxton" UI for creating/accessing the databases.

CouchDB is accessible from the url  `http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils`.

These pages discuss the problem but don't give any detailed steps on how to solve the problem:

- https://github.com/apache/couchdb-docker/issues/42
- https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/issues/1049
- https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/pull/999

Comment: According to the fix, the accept field was missing the JSON content-type. Also, even if it's not recommended, you can build the latest Fauxton and paste it into the /share/www folder to update Fauxton

Comment: You may use Photon as an admin panel, see https://github.com/ermouth/couch-photon